# I want to push product object into an array in liquid file

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to push product object into an array in liquid file.

```
{% assign notebooks = null | sort %}
{% paginate  collections['entire-collection'].products by collections['entire-collection'].all_products_count %} 
  
 {% for newProduct in collections['entire-collection'].products %}
   
   {% assign variant_details= newProduct.selected_or_first_available_variant %}  
  {% if handle contains newProduct.title and newProduct.id != current_id %}
    {% if current_price > newProduct.price and newProduct.available %}
     {% assign notebook = newProduct | sort %}
    {% assign notebooks = notebooks | append: notebook %}
       {%  assign product = newProduct %}
      {% assign current_variant = newProduct.selected_or_first_available_variant %} 
<!--       {% break %} -->
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}   
{% endfor %}
  {% endpaginate %}
```

i tried this code but not working.

```
{% assign notebooks = null | sort %}
{% assign notebook = product | sort %}
{% assign notebooks = notebooks | push: notebook %}
```

I will push products into an array then i need to loop these new product array.

Comment: you can't do the push directly into liquid code, it doesn't supported.

Comment: any other way to achieve that?

Comment: can you please explain the logic behind this, so I can suggest you best way to do into liquid

Comment: I am looping all product of a collection and in loop i have a if condition to get lowest price, if this condition matches then i will create a new array of lowest price products, then i will show these lowest price product in the section.

Comment: you mean you want to show only the lowest price firstly like sorting?

Comment: Yes, I have update my question with the code

Comment: on which page you tried the code, because some terms are still missing like current_price, handle and current_id

Comment: you tried `concat` instead of append [Link](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/array-filters?shpxid=9ba7856d-9D7A-48C8-BEEF-E1D99B5456D2#concat)?

Comment: it is in product template, Please dont consider other condition. I just want to push this newProduct object into an array

Comment: you can't do the same into liquid code, but you apply diff logic to achieve it. yo need to do into this way.

Comment: What ever your logic, when it meets the condition, simply extract the handle to the product and append it into the string using comma.

Comment: then split the string and loop the handle and get the product data using all_products global object.